# Set cookie then immediantly refresh the page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, cookies

I wrote a small WordPress plugin ([mobileesp-for-wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobileesp-for-wordpress/)) that will redirect mobile users to the mobile site. It's based on [mobileesp](http://blog.mobileesp.com/).

The plugin itself works fine the problem is I added an option to view the full site. This function works by checking for a cookie and if the cookie is there don't redirect the user to the mobile site.

This also works but the user must click the link twice. Once to set the cookie and the second time to take them back into the WordPress site. The full code can be found [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/mobileesp-for-wordpress/trunk/mobileesp_wp.php) but I think this is the relevent part.

```
$get_cookie_check = $_GET['view_full_site'];
if(isset($get_cookie_check)){
    if($get_cookie_check =='true'){
        //set the cookie
        setcookie("mobileesp_wp_full_site", 'true', time()+86400, "/", $domain);
    }
}
//cookie variable
$full_site_cookie= $_COOKIE['mobileesp_wp_full_site']; 

//make sure the target url is set and full site cookie isn't set
if((get_option('mobileesp_wp_target_url') != '') && ($full_site_cookie !="true")){
    //check for a mobile browser and redirect the user 
}
```

}

The temporary solution would be to check for the cookie on the mobile site then redirect them but is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) function prepares the HTTP cookie header to be sent at the next page load. That's why the `$_COOKIE` superglobal is not updated automatically.

You could manually update `$_COOKIE` for use on the current request. Just put this below your `setcookie()` line:

```
$_COOKIE['mobileesp_wp_full_site'] = 'true';
```

By the way, I'd prefer not to work with strings like `'true'`, but just with integers (`0` and `1`). You then can simply check them like this: `! empty($_GET['view_full_site'])`.

Comment: I took your advice and am not using 0 and 1 for cookie values thanks!